# Поясните работу атрибута data

Tags: html, jquery

Второй день не могу понять принцип работы, задавал уже этот вопрос но так и не получил нужного ответа.Есть попап,при открытии его меняется значение атрибута data,после клика по кнопке в попапе хочу получить значение атрибута дата но оно сохраняет только значение первого открытого попапа!

```
    <!-- HOLIDAYS FORM TEMPLATE -->
        <script id="holidaysFormTpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <form action=""  class="tr for-clone item active" data-hol-id="{{:id}}">
                <div class="td parent">
                    <div class="wrapp-input  edit v_name">
                        <input type="text" class="input-val" name="name" placeholder="Holiday" value="{{:name}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="td parent">
                    <div class="wrapp-input  edit">
                        <input type="text" id="choose_date" name="start_date" value="{{:start_date}}" class="date-pick" placeholder="Choose date">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="td right-align">
                    <a href="#" class="btn waves-effect waves-light ml-10 small  save-this-row add-holiday">Save it</a>
                </div>
                <div class="td right-align">
                    <a href="#" class="trash-ico "><span class="ico icon-trash "></span></a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </script>

//SAVE HOLIDAYS
    $('.holidays-box').on('click', '.save-this-row', function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var parentItem = btn.parents('.item');

        console.log(btn.closest('.modal-content .holidays-box').data());
    }
```

5 кликов по разным попапам,значение одно и то же,первого открытого.

```
Object {depId: 145}
Object {depId: 145}
Object {depId: 145}
Object {depId: 145}
Object {depId: 145}
```

Нашел в интернете вот такое. Тогда зачем нужна data если значение сохраняется изначальное?

```
Один минус (а может и не минус) — это то, что в data() сохранится только изначальное значение (кешируется),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из прочитанного в интернете понял что `data` берет значение не из DOM, чтобы работать с аттрибутами `DOM` моделе нужно использовать `attr`.

Answer (score 1):

если ты хочешь получить дата, допустим у тебя есть test чтобы получить data-id-hold ты пишешь вот так `$('.test').on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).data('id-hold'));
});`
Если же вы использовали словосочетание через дефис, то вы сможете получить его в camelCase:
То это получится так id-hold = idHold
или обратиться к этому тегу через data можно через $('[data-id-hold="123"]') и повешать событие, data-* для хранения параметров и получения их в js 
https://jsfiddle.net/hvx8qfnf/1/ вот пример

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере не вся разметка, додумывать как-то трудно. Рекомендую сделать пример кода в jsfiddle.net там можно и jquery и bootstrap добавить в меню, вот пример с тем и тем и экземплом с сайта getbootstrap.com
(https://jsfiddle.net/kLpb245b/)

html

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```